# Kotlin gradle is getting confused about it's project home

Tags: kotlin, gradle

in build.gradle.kts I have

```
rootProject.name = "adaptors"
// I have also used File("."), same results
file(".").walkTopDown().filter { it.extension == "sln" }.map { it.path.split('/','\\')[1]  }.forEach(::include)
```

If I run this in `kotlinc` it works as expected:

```
>>> File(".").walkTopDown().filter { it.extension == "sln" }.map { it.path.split('/','\\')[1]  }.take(5).forEach{println(it)}
adaptor-cwi_ca_los_angeles
adaptor-socwi_vt
adaptor-qc_oh_butler
adaptor-pwi_tx_mc_tor
adaptor-fdi_globex
```

However, when I ask gradle to show me it's projects:

```
cbongiorno at 5cg6203867 in ~/dev/adaptors on INIT-471 [!?]

$ gradle projects

> Task :projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'adaptors'
\--- Project ':Users'

To see a list of the tasks of a project, run gradle <project-path>:tasks
For example, try running gradle :Users:tasks
```

Ok, that's all wrong. But, when I ask it for the properties it has to show me the projectDir, it's actually right!

```
cbongiorno at 5cg6203867 in ~/dev/adaptors on INIT-471 [!?]
$ gradle properties

...
projectDir: /Users/cbongiorno/dev/adaptors
```

Here is bash code confirming my understanding:

```
cbongiorno at 5cg6203867 in ~/dev/adaptors on INIT-471 [!?]
$ pwd
/Users/cbongiorno/dev/adaptors

cbongiorno at 5cg6203867 in ~/dev/adaptors on INIT-471 [!?]
$ ls *.kts
build.gradle.kts    settings.gradle.kts

cbongiorno at 5cg6203867 in ~/dev/adaptors on INIT-471 [!?]
$ ls Users
ls: Users: No such file or directory
```

Now, even more shocking is that, assuming this was parented wrong, the tree walk code would still find all the solution files and STILL work properly. Except, this causes other code to blow up because, DUH! the directory doesn't even exist.

I get the exact same issue on windows and mac.

So, exactly how is gradle coming to these conclusions, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Long story short**: It actually works with `File(".")`

---

The Gradle method [`file(Object path)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:file(java.lang.Object)) always returns an absolute file path, as any relative path is interpreted relative to the project directory.

The Kotlin method `walkTopDown` seems to return relative file paths if given a relative input path and absolute file paths if given an absolute input path. For relative file paths, `it.path.split('/','\\')[1]` will actually return the name of the parent directory of the `.sln` files, however for absolute file paths it will return the name of the first folder after the filesystem root (e.g. `Users` for `/Users/cbongiorno/dev/adaptors`). This is the reason why Gradle creates a subproject called `Users`.

Gradle does not care that there is no actual directory with this name, as it does not care about missing or empty `build.gradle` files, too. You may even completely configure a project from other projects build scripts via `project(':<path>')`, `subprojects` or `allprojects`.

Comment: VERY insightful!